# Need clarification on authentication and keeping user logged in

Tags: angular, authentication, asp.net-web-api, cookies

I am building app with Angular 15 (FE) and ASP.NET Core 6 (BE).

I have implemented cookie based authentication - on successful logging in I'm sending a single `app-session` cookie that contains two claims representing users' unique identifier and username. Now that there is the cookie that is attached to every request, on page reloading I want to automatically display text like "Hello, {*USERNAME*}". How can I achieve this?

The way I currently see this is that I need to send additional request to server to retrieve user identity. But from what I can see on other web-sites information about user is already present in initial html document itself without any additional fetch/xhr.

Comment: Save your identifier and username in localstorage.

Comment: @N.F. Do I save it as plain text or transform it as token first?

Comment: Values in localstorage are just string. you can save them in plain text.